# User.DoesNotExist - catch exception value

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to write a `confirm` function to confirm the registration by a user.

Simple logic: A user registers and gets an email. During registration I create hash value to make sure all users have unique value in my db and I send an email to the user asking to confirm the registration. And on the confirm link in email I put that hash value as a confirm id for this registration.

After the user has clicked, this function will be called:

```
def confirm(request):
  hash_id = request.GET.get('id')
  try: 
    user = User.objects.get(uniq_hashed__exact=hash_id)
    user.confirmed = 'yes'
    email = user.email
    user.save()
    request.session['sess_id'] = hash_id
    message = "activated!"
    return render_to_response('danke.html',{'email':email},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  except User.DoesNotExist: 
    sorry = "Sorry, you dont exist in our db :("
    return render_to_response('danke.html',{'danke':sorry},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, I am always getting `Sorry, you don't exist in our db :(` even though the hash value is in the db and matches the url id.

why is this? Can I read the exact message of `DoesNotExist` exception?

I played with User model a lot and had to restore the old db after deleting some data, did reset, did reset of South and many other things.

Could this be the reason for this problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More info will certainly be useful (database schema, User model code) but this'll get you exception text (something along the lines "User matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'uniq_hashed': 'c9b8568a4c19e74b5bddd05bd71caac1'}").

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(uniq_hashed__exact=hash_id)
except User.DoesNotExist as exc:
    message = str(exc)
```